# Trying to understand the MySQL/PHP/JSON/Restful/Android relationship

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, retrofit

I'm making an android app that will have a backend database (MySQL).

From my research, it seems like one of the ways to connect to a MySQL database is to use PHP to make an HTTP request to the database, which will then return data in the form of a JSON object which is decoded.

```
PHP is used to make a GET/POST to the database (often using a service like Retrofit) 
The database fetches or posts the appropriate data and must alert the client/return data
The database sends back information that is JSON form
The client decodes the returned JSON
```

Is this the correct logic? 
Why is PHP needed to make the request?  Is this an acceptable way of interacting with a MySQL database from an android app? Do you have any advice to offer for going about this?

Comment: PHP is not specifically needed, and many would argue that it's a poor choice that nobody should ever use for any purpose... but you either need it, or *some* kind of web-enabled programming language or framework/environment (Express, OpenResty, Mojolicious, or one of seemingly countless others), to power the application server... to, at minimum, mediate and authenticate the requests from the app over the web, send them to the db, and serialize the response.  You do not want the app communicating directly with the db, for many, many reasons, including numerous security and scalability issues.

Answer (score 2):

If your are using the LAN MYSQL server in your own device, you can use MYSQL command to connect the server

```
try
    {        
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
         String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+serverip+":"+serverport+"/"+dbName;
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
         String queryString = "SELECT * FROM materialdb"; 
         PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
         ResultSet rss = statement.executeQuery(queryString);

         results = new ArrayList<FindDetails>();

         rss.beforeFirst();
             while(rss.next())
                {         
                 FindDetails item_details = new FindDetails();
                item_details.setMaterial_Code_No(rss.getString("Material_Code_No"));
                results.add(item_details);          
                }                          
         rss.close();
         statement.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fail to get main list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If the server is on web, the better way of connect to server is PHP

Answer (score 0):

This approach looks like it is for a web server, not a client (much less an Android client). Usually, servers have databases and clients are "consumers" of that data. However, clients also usually have databases to store that data.

PHP is a server-side technology whereby you can use a URL and HTTP to send and retrieve data. PHP can then be used to connect to a database to provide rich content to the client.

In Android, your device (likely) will not have a URL or website. It can have a database and you can use HTTP libraries (like Retrofit - http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to get data from websites (that might use HTTP). But this is *passive* - your client will have to request data, the server cannot "push" data to it.

For "push" data, you can use Firebase (Google Cloud Messaging) which uses a Google framework and API to have a (reasonably) constant connection to the device to "push" notifications to it. If you follow their rules, you will send a small data packet that tells your client to wake and start making specific HTTP requests to whatever URL you like.